# Build string as in printf function

Tags: c++, string, printf

```
printf("%d.%d.%d", year, month, day);
```

Can I do the same but without printing, smth like

```
char* date = "%d.%d.%d", year, month, day;
```

Or maybe some other simple ways to do that?

Comment: Which version of C++? In Visual C++, you have `CString.Format` for instance...

Comment: @MrLister thanks, that was helpful. In order to convert CString to char* one can use CString::GetBuffer().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In plain c there is asprintf() which will allocate memory to hold the resulting string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *date;
asprintf(&date, "%d.%d.%d", year, month, day);
```

(error handling omitted)

Since you have tagged C++ you probably want to use the C++ solutions.

Comment: Error handling being "if `asprintf` returns `-1`, instead of the length of the formatted string, it failed."

Comment: I wouldn't call it "plain C", `asprintf` is not a standard function.

Comment: Standard is what BSD has :) No seriously, "plain c" meant "not C++", and yes, IIRC you need to define _GNU_SOURCE on Linux (glibc actually) to get it.

Answer (score 3):

In C++:

```
#include <string>

std::string date = std::to_string(year) + '.' +
                   std::to_string(month) + '.' + std::to_string(day);
```

If you need the underlying `char const *`, say `date.c_str()`.

The function `std::to_string` uses `snprintf` internally; you should probably look up that function, too, as it is fairly fundamental to formatted output, and you can use it directly if you really think you need to.

Comment: Note that this was added in C++11, so it may not be supported by all compilers and/or default build flags.

Comment: This avoids the entire purpose of the question, which was to use printf style syntax rather than plain string concatenation

Answer (score 2):

There are various implementations of a `format` function that looks something like:

```
std::string format(const std::string& fmt, ...);
```

so your example would be:

```
std::string date = format("%d.%d.%d", year, month, day);
```

One possible implementation is shown below.

Boost has a [format library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) that works a little differently. It assumes you like `cin`, `cout`, and their ilk:

```
cout << boost::format("%1%.%2%.%3%") % year % month % day;
```

Or, if you just wanted a string:

```
boost::format fmt("%1%.%2%.%3%");
fmt % year % month % day;
std::string date = fmt.str();
```

Note that `%` flags are not the ones you're used to.

Finally, if you want a C string (`char*`) instead of a C++ `string`, you could use the [`asprintf` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf):

```
char* date; 
if(asprintf(&date, "%d.%d.%d", year, month, day) == -1)
{ /* couldn't make the string; format was bad or out of memory. */ }
```

You could even use `vasprintf` to make your own `format` function returning a C++ string:

```
std::string format(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    char* result = 0;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    if(vasprintf(*result, fmt, ap) == -1)
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    va_end(ap);
    std::string str_result(result);
    free(result);
    return str_result;
}
```

This isn't terribly efficient, but it works. There also might be a way to call `vsnprintf` twice, the first with no buffer to get the formatted string length, then allocate the string object with the right capacity, then call the second time to get the string. This avoids allocating the memory twice, but has to make two passes through the formatted string.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ I wrote a [function](https://github.com/gisodal/exception) to create strings using the printf format.

Headerfile **stringf.h**:

```
#ifndef STRINGF_H
#define STRINGF_H

#include <string>

template< typename... argv >
std::string stringf( const char* format, argv... args ) {
    const size_t SIZE = std::snprintf( NULL, 0, format, args... );

    std::string output;
    output.resize(SIZE+1);
    std::snprintf( &(output[0]), SIZE+1, format, args... );
    return std::move(output);
}

#endif
```

Usage:

```
#include "stringf.h"

int main(){
    int year = 2020;
    int month = 12;
    int day = 20
    std::string date = stringf("%d.%d.%d", year, month, day);
    // date == "2020.12.20"
}
```

Comment: FWIW this is very slow. using asprintf and returning a string is ~3x faster, which returning a std::vector<char> is ~10% slower than that. Using reserve instead of resize is slightly faster

Answer (score 1):

In C language use `sprintf` function from `stdio.h` header file.

```
char  buffer[100];
sprintf(buffer,"%d.%d.%d", year, month, day);
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) for more info.